# Move position in FileStream (C#)

Tags: c#, filestream

I have a txt file like this

```
#header1
#header2
#header3
....
#headerN
ID Value Pvalue
a  0.1  0.002
b  0.2  0.002
...
```

My code will try to parse

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileMode.Read);
......
Table t = Table.Load(fs);
```

what I want is to make the start position of the Stream right before "ID", so I can feed the stream to the code and make a new table. But I am not sure what is the correct way to do it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the header size fixed? you could set the position of the stream if it's fixed size  e.g. s.Position = 20;

Comment: @SvenB: The header size is flexible

Comment: Save position, use `StreamReader.ReadLine` to check whether there's another header, if yes loop, if not, set the position back, then `Table.Load()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should convert `Table.Load` to take an `IEnumerable<string>` or at least a `StreamReader`, not a raw `Stream`.

If this is not an option, you can read the whole file into memory, skip its header, and write the result into `MemoryStream`:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName).SkipWhile(s => s.StartsWith("#"))) {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
stream.Position = 0;
Table t = Table.Load(stream);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        const string file = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
            string inputline = "";
            State state = State.FIND_HEADER;
            while((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case State.FIND_HEADER:
                        if (inputline.StartsWith("#header"))
                        {
                            state = State.READ_TABLE;
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.READ_TABLE:
                        Table t = Table.Load(fs);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        enum State
        {
            FIND_HEADER,
            READ_TABLE
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No.  Not is not needed.    The user want to start reading on the ID line.  So the code will readline after "#header" and get next line.